# Processing - How do I show a quadrant of the screen in a larger frame?

Tags: processing

I want I have a splitscreen video that is split into 4 quadrants. I want to use Processing to take a clicked quadrant, and show the view in a larger, frame or window that is centered. Below I already have a click function and a called mousePressed(). You can also find code that helps you identify which quadrant you are dealing with. Each quadrant is noted just in case.

```java
import peasy.*;
import peasy.org.apache.commons.math.*;
import peasy.org.apache.commons.math.geometry.*;
import processing.video.*;
import ddf.minim.*;
import processing.video.*;
String Path = "/Users/Gameheads/Desktop/Video1/POV Sports Prototype.mp4";

PeasyCam cam;
Movie myMovie;
Minim minim;
int boxSize = 75;
boolean overBox = false;
boolean locked = false;
float bx;
float by;
int boxNumber;
//AudioPlayer floor;

// Three variables for the background color.
float r = 0;
float b = 0;
float g = 0;
float a = 0;
// transparency rgba(100, 0, 0, 0)
void setup() {
    background(r, g, b, a);
    frameRate(30);
    size(1280, 720);
    // minim = new Minim(this);
    //floor = minim.loadFile("Floor.mp3", 512);
    myMovie = new Movie(this, Path);  
    // colorMode(HSB);
    myMovie.play();
}


//Each Rectangle size should be 320x180  
//XY (00)
//(X,Y,width, height)
void draw() {

    image(myMovie, 0, 0, width, height); // draws video

    // Draw the box
    rect (0, 0, 55, 55); //Top Left, add 320 x 180 end
    rect(640, 0, 55, 55); //Top Right, add 320 x 180 end
    rect(0, 360, 55, 55); //Bottom Left
    rect(640, 360, 55, 55); //Bottom right

    // background(r,g,b);  
    stroke(255);
    line(width/2,0,width/2,height);
    line(0,height/2,width,height/2);

    // Test if the cursor is over first gray square
    if (mouseX > bx-boxSize && mouseX < bx+boxSize && 
        mouseY > by-boxSize && mouseY < by+boxSize) {
        overBox = true;  
        if(!locked) { 
            stroke(255, 0, 255); 
            fill(153);
        } 
    }
    //Bottom Right Quadrant
    else if (mouseY > height/2 && mouseX >= 640) {
        overBox = true;  
        if(!locked) { 
            stroke(255, 0, 255); 
            fill(153);
        } 
    }
    //Bottom Left Quadrant
    else if  (mouseY > height/2 && mouseX < 640) 
    {
        stroke(255, 255, 125);
        fill(153);
    }
    // top right Quadrant
    else if (mouseY < height/2 && mouseX >= 640) {
        overBox = true;  
        if(!locked) { 
            stroke(0, 0, 255); 
            fill(153);
        } 
    }
    //Top Left Quadrant
    else if  (mouseY < height/2 && mouseX < 640)
    {
        overBox = true;  
        if(locked){
            stroke(255, 0, 0);
            fill(153);
        }
    } 
}

// Called every time a new frame is available to read
void movieEvent(Movie m) {
    m.read();
}  

void mousePressed() {
    if(overBox) { 
        locked = true; 
        fill (255, 255, 255);
    } 
}
void mouseReleased() {
    locked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense:

You need to [split your problem up into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then take on those pieces one at a time. It's good that you started by writing a program that identifies which quadrant. But now I'd recommend creating a **separate** program that just shows a new window whenever you click anywhere in the first window. Don't worry about the video, just get that working by itself. **Hint:** Do a search for the `PApplet.runSketch()` function.

Separately from that, create a simple program that just draws a quadrant of an **image** (not a video) to the screen. You might use the `createGraphics()` function to help with this. Use an image, that way you don't have to worry about a whole video, plus it's easier for us to help you if you get stuck.

Get those things working perfectly by themselves before you start thinking about combining them. Then if you get stuck on a specific step, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of just that step. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will post the MCVE if/when I have another issue.